# GCP map load balancer to custom port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I'm trying to point my external load balancer to backend runs on port 4440, but I don't know what's missing tho the health check works fine.

And accessing the service from inside the managed instance(using wget) is working.

when I try to access the page using the load-balancer IP I'm getting a text says "stream timeout"
and I'm allowing all traffic from LB IP.

So, what is that I'm missing here?
I added a health check for the port that service running at and it's working.

[health_check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyIFM.png)

[instance_group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj9zM.png)

[loadbalancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea4cE.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aajRE.png)

[loadbalancer_allow_fw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3aCx.png)

[firewall_rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmGej.png)

Answer (score 1):

From this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-l7-internal#gcloud_7):

> The Ingress controller does not create a firewall rule to allow connections from the load balancer proxies in the proxy-subnet. You must create this firewall rule manually.

so when you need access to an internal load balancer from a network that is not in the VPC of the load balancer you will need to allow the traffic you desire to reach your Service. You can do it by using below command:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create l7-ilb-forwarding-rule-global-access \
  --load-balancing-scheme=INTERNAL_MANAGED \
  --network=lb-network \
  --subnet=backend-subnet \
  --address=10.1.2.99 \
  --ports=80 \
  --region=us-west1 \
  --target-http-proxy=l7-ilb-proxy \
  --target-http-proxy-region=us-west1 \
  --allow-global-access
```

If it does not resolve your issue, try checking the firewall and let me know if the default VPC firewall rule was blocking GKE node VM instance, try providing 0.0.0.0/0 allow temporarily, check this [firewall configuration](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal#firewall_configuration) document .

Comment: I'm trying to link "Regional external Application Load Balancer" to "Instance Group", I'm not using GKE.  and can you please help me understand what address this refers to "--address=10.1.2.99"?

Comment: For IP address, you can either select the same IP address as an existing forwarding rule, reserve a new IP address, or use an ephemeral IP address. Sharing the same IP address across multiple forwarding rules is only possible if you set the IP address --purpose flag to SHARED\_LOADBALANCER\_VIP while creating the IP address.